# Am I selecting the div's children correctly?

Tags: jquery

I have a screen that adds circles to a div that is the "board". The circles append to the board and I have buttons that do a variety of things. The one I am struggling with is "Move". Currently the circles do not move at all but I have previously been able to get all of them to move in a direction but never switch directions.

I'm not sure if it is how SetInterval works or how I'm selecting each circle or how I might be setting my switch variables. I've tried changing each.

```
//start of page
$(document).ready(function(){
function getRandomColor(){
    var letters="0123456789abcdef";
    var result ="#";

    for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        result+=letters.charAt(parseInt(Math.random()*letters.length));
    }
    return result;
}
function addCircle(){

var circle=$('<div class="circle"</div>');

    $("#board").append(circle);
    $(circle).css({
    left : (Math.random() * ($("#board").width() - $(circle).width())),
    top : (Math.random() * ($("#board").height() - $(circle).height())),
    background: getRandomColor()
  });



}






$("#move").click(function move(){
  var stop;
    if (stop==true){
      clearInterval(id);
    }
      else {
        stop=true;
      $("#board").each(function(){
        var switchx = true;
        var switchy=true;
        var circle1 = $(this).child;

        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
           function frame() {
           var x = $(circle1).position();
          if (switchx==false) {
                if(x.left<0)
                {
                  switchx=true;
                  $(circle1).css({background: getRandomColor()});
                }
                  else { $(circle1).css({
                  left:  x.left-3,
                 });
              }
        }
        else if(switchx==true) {
                if(x.left>400){

                  switchx=false;
                  $(circle1).css({background: getRandomColor()});
                }
                else {$(circle1).css({
                  left: x.left+3,
                 });
              }
          }
          if (switchy==false) {
                if(x.top<0){
                  switchy=true;
                  $(circle1).css({background: getRandomColor()});
                  }
                  else { $(circle1).css({
                  top:  x.top+3,
                 });
              }
          }

              else if(switchy==true) {
                if(x.top>400){
                  switchy=false;
                  $(circle1).css({background: getRandomColor()});
                }
                else {$(circle1).css({
                  top: x.top-3,
                 });
              }
          }



          }
       });//each
    }
 });//move




$("#add").click(function(e)
{
    addCircle();
});

$("#change").click(function(e)
{
    $(".circle").each(function color(){
        $(this).css({
            background: getRandomColor()
        });
    });
});

$("#reset").click(function(e){
$(".circle").remove();
for (var i=0;i<49;i++)
addCircle();
});

$( "#board" ).on("dblclick", ".circle", function() {
  $( this ).remove();
});

$( "#board" ).on("click", ".circle", function() {
    $(this).css('zIndex', z);
    z++;
});

function remove(){
    var node = document.getElementByClass("circle");
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
//rest of code
var z=999;
var go=false;
for(var i=0;i<49;i++)
addCircle();


});//end
```

```
<div id="board">

            </div>
          </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id ="spread">
          <button id="add">
            add
          </button>
          <button id="change">
            change color
          </button>
          <button id="reset">
            reset
          </button>
          <button id="move">
            move
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
```

```
#board{
    border-width:  2px;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#spread{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Each circle should move in a direction then change direction when it his the edge of the board. I believe my borders are off right not but that isn't a big deal at the moment.

This was previously an assignment of mine but I am using/upgrading it for my personal website.

Comment: `$("#board").each(function(){...` This implies that there is more than one `#board`...

Comment: Changing it to #circles causes the circles to move into one direction. Are my variables for switchx and switchy set correctly? I only ask because wouldn't they be shared by each circle?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55358782/2813224) regarding your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `move()` function of OP (**O**riginal **P**ost) was nowhere near being functional at all. It's so flawed I don't know where to begin so here's some suggestions:

- Define your variables early as possible.
   **ex.** in `move()` `var stop` was declared but never defined and there' an `if/else` condition depending on it's existence.
- jQuery is very versatile concerning element access so don't need to use ids you will have an easier time just using class.
   **ex.** In the demo all ids have been converted to classes. The use of `$('.circle').each()` allows us to assign each `.circle` random CSS properties.
- Never use `.each()` on an id.
  **ex.** `$('#board').each()` and `$('#circle').each()` is a code stink. `.each()` will run a function over each element within the given jQuery collection:

  > `$(` **jQuery Collection** `).each(function(index, element) {` 
  > /*current element==>*/ `$(this).css({....` //⇧ current index position
- A jQuery collection can be a group of various elements that match the selector.
  **ex.** `$(".circle")` references all elements with the class of `.circle`.
- Animations and transitions by CSS are optimal using `transform` -- avoid `position`.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// returns a number in the range of min to max (inclusive)
function rand(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

/*
returns a string: "rgba(255, 0, 128, 0.5)"
The min and max params set each color's alpha and is
offset by a decimal. ex. Alpha (opacity) of 0.3 is 3 - the
valid values are 1 to 10 and min cannot be greater than
max of course.
*/
function getRGBa(min, max) {
  let blk = [0, 0, 0];
  let rgba = blk.map(num => num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
  rgba.push(rand(min, max));
  return `rgba(${rgba[0]}, ${rgba[1]}, ${rgba[2]}, ${(rgba[3]*0.1).toPrecision(1)})`;
}

// Generates, positions, and fills the color of a .circle
function addCircle() {
  let color = getRGBa(5, 10);
  let circle = $('<figure class="circle" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);"></figure>');
  circle.css({
    'left': (Math.random() * ($(".board").width() - circle.width())),
    'top': (Math.random() * ($(".board").height() - circle.height())),
    'background-color': color
  });
  $(".board").append(circle);
}

// Changes background-color of each .circle
function changeColors() {
  $('.circle').each(function() {
    let color = getRGBa(5, 10);
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
  });
}

/*
Moves each .circle at a random speed, distance, and
direction. Transitions and transforms are used.
*/
function moveCircles() {
  $('.circle').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'transform': `translate(${rand(-100, 100)}px, ${rand(-100, 100)}px)`,
      'transition': `${rand(1, 10)*0.1}s`
    });
  });
}

// Removes all circles
function clearCircles() {
  $('.circle').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}

// All event handlers
$('.add').on('click', addCircle);
$('.color').on('click', changeColors);
$('.move').on('click', moveCircles);
$('.clear').on('click', clearCircles);
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1 Arial;
}

.board {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class='container'>
    <section class="row">
      <form id='ui' class='col'>
        <fieldset class="board border border-success rounded"></fieldset>
        <section class='row'>
          <article class='col'>
            <fieldset class="btn-toolbar justify-content-between">
              <label class='btn-group'>
            <button class="btn btn-success add" type='button'>ADD</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success color" type='button'>COLOR</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success move" type='button'>MOVE</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success clear" type='reset'>CLEAR</button>
            </label>
            </fieldset>
          </article>
        </section>
      </form>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```